# Can't connect remotely to MySQL database over network

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, mysql, port

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database that's set up on a Linux Mint installation however I can't connect to it through MySQL Workbench:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at
10.0.0.5:3306 with user root

Unable to connect to localhost
```

nor can I establish a connection with Test-NetConnection:

```
PS C:\Users\LOUIS-PC> Test-NetConnection 10.0.0.5 -Port 3306
WARNING: TCP connect to (10.0.0.5 : 3306) failed


ComputerName           : 10.0.0.5
RemoteAddress          : 10.0.0.5
RemotePort             : 3306
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 10.0.0.72
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 6 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

I can connect to the server locally on the machine but other connections on the same network don't work.
I've already opened an exception for the firewall on the Linux machine but it still doesn't work:

```
louis@louis-1015PX:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                  Action    From
--                  -----     ----
3306/tcp            ALLOW     Anywhere
3306/tcp (v6)       ALLOW     Anywhere (v6)
```

My /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf file is as follows:

```
[mysql]
port = 3306
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

My mysql.user table is as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = "root";
+------+
| host |
+------+
| %    |
-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

I needed to set the `bind-address` to `0.0.0.0` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`